# How can I override the styling of an MUI checkbox which I have not written?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using Material-Table to display data.  I am using the `columnsButton` property in table options to allow users to hide columns.  I want to override the checkboxes that appear to align with my color scheme.

The `columnsButton` property adds this small icon next to the search bar.  Clicking it opens the popover seen below.  Unchecking the options here will hide columns from the table.  I do not have to write any extra code for this popover.  It is a native feature of Material-Table.

I want to change the border color and checked color of these checkboxes to match my color theme.

[image]

Here is my table:

```
            <MaterialTable
                title=""
                data={intakes.intakes}
                columns={columns}
                icons={tableIcons}
                options={{
                    columnsButton: true
                }}
            />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ThemeProvider` to override the default css.
 Codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-review-forked-06y5zf